# Can I use scikit-learn pipeline to transform a specific variable only?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Reading [scikit-learn doc on Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html), all the examples apply the transformers on the entire dataset (e.g. `StandardScaler`, `PCA`).

Is it possible to, say, only scale a specific variable in the dataset? If this is possible, then I can put my entire feature engineering process into a Pipeline and apply it on both my train and test sets.

Comment: See this example : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) and custom transformers that take only the variable you're interested in.

However, you're right in that sklearn does not handle heterogeneous feature sets particularly well. There is a library [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/sklearn-pandas) which makes it a lot easier, letting you define separate pipelines for specific columns of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: So for feature engineering in practice, do we just transform each variable, then copy paste the process on the test set? This is actually not too bad -- using R one would do the same. I was just too excited about `scikit-learn`'s Pipeline.

Comment: Yep, I understand. Yes, I think that's the process vanilla sklearn requires for heterogeneous features. I would encourage looking at the linked sklearn-pandas library, however. Lends a lot more flexibility to the pipeline.